# How to Update Column,whose datatype is DateTime

Tags: sql, database

I have table named as **dbo.SetCustomerRFMComData** with eight columns.

In which the third column name is **RecDatetime** whose DataType is **DATETIME**

I update the **table** using an **stored procedure**.

How to add current **Datetime** in **RecDateTime column** while firing an **UPDATE QUERY**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server use `GETDATE()` .

In MySQL and PostgreSQL , use `NOW()`.

In Oracle , use `SYSDATE`.

Comment: In the Update query, i m not able to use the Datetime column.

Comment: Update SetCustomerRFMComData SET  LicenseKey=@License,IsVerified=@Isverfiy where SerialNumber=@SerialNumber

Comment: The Following are the Table name:-Firstname,Lastname,EmailiD,Address,SerialNumber,LicenseKey,Isverified,RecDatetime. and i want to update Licensekey,Isverified and RecDatetime column.

Comment: Update SetCustomerRFMComData SET LicenseKey=@License,IsVerified=@Isverfiy,RecDatetime = GetDate() where SerialNumber=@SerialNumber

Comment: It is giving me -"Invalid Column Name"- RecDatetime.

Comment: I think restriction have put in place on column , see this thread....http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/restrict-update-on-certain-columns-only-allow-stored-procedure-to-update-those

Answer (score -1):

Call GETDATE() method which will update you current date time

Suppose your sp looks like this

create procedure sp_proc
(
@RecTime Datetime 
)

as
begin

set @RecTime =DateTime()
update tablename values(RecTime=@RecTime )
end

Comment: In the Update Query, the Datetime column name is not visible to set it  time by using RecDateTime=GETDATE()